# Is it okay to use watch to keep track of store changes after initial mount?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say I have a component that is loaded with data from an initial API call inside mounted().

Any further changes to a state variable will not be reflected in the component since the first API call is inside mounted.

Can we use watcher to deal with this?

For Example,

```
data() {
return {
 someVariableInStore: this.$store.state.test,
 variableThatUpdatesTheComponent: ""
},

watch: {
   someVariableInStore(){
     // Based on someVariableInStore run a function that updates variableThatUpdatesTheComponent
        someFunction();
}
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this if not the above solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach in this case is to use a [computed property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components). Instead of manually calling the update function, let Vue call it for you:

```js
computed: {
  variableThatUpdatesTheComponent() {
    // The logic of `someFunction()` can go here
    return this.$store.state.test + "foo";
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't need to return anything, which is why I wasn't using computed.

Comment: @manb If you'll refer to the documentation link above, you'll see that the return statement here is essentially variable assignment. The value you return will become the value of `variableThatUpdatesTheComponent`. Computed properties are essentially equivalent to writing a watcher that assigns to a variable, but the syntax is shorter and everything is handled for you by Vue.